# GWT Visualization AnnotatedTimeLine graph giving exception Container height is zero

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I am trying to use AnnotatedTimeLine graph provided in GWT Visualization and i am getting following exception

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Container height is zero. Expecting a valid height.
stack: Error: Container height is zero. Expecting a valid height.

My View class codes is like below

void onButtonLineGraphClick(ClickEvent event) {
         Runnable onLoadCallback1 = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                AnnotatedTimeLine timeline = new AnnotatedTimeLine(createLineTable(), createOptionsLine(),
                                "200", "200"); 
                panelGraph.setHeight("200");
                panelGraph.setWidth("200");
                panelGraph.add(timeline);
              }
            };
            VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback1, AnnotatedTimeLine.PACKAGE);
}

And Pannel Graph is defined like below in ui.xml

g:HTMLPanel width = "200px" height="200px" ui:field="panelGraph"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnnotatedTimeLine timeline = new AnnotatedTimeLine(createLineTable(), createOptionsLine(), "200", "200");

Should be replace with

AnnotatedTimeLine timeline = new AnnotatedTimeLine(createLineTable(), createOptionsLine(), "200px", "200px");

finally got it...